# Getting javaScript code from a script tag using Selenium: Is that possible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm getting an error from the last line of the code below

```
// Scala code
val driver: HtmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
val el = driver.findElementByXPath(xp)
val js = el.getText()
```

the "el" element returned is a "script" tag. I was wondering if is possible or not to get the content of the tag using .getText()

Here's the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes u can get the content of a script by using attribute like this el.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, it is not possible to access the content of a "script" element using XPath. The solution I found to this issue was to apply a regular expression on the HTML source:

```
// Scala code
val regex = "your (pattern)".r
val res = ( regex findFirstMatchIn driver.getPageSource() ).get group 1
```